# How to Backup a Partition Completely to Microsoft OneDrive in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, backup, onedrive, partition

I have an One-drive Account with 1 TB of Storage. Also I have three Partitions on Windows namely Windows(C:), Media(D:), Documents(E:). I want to backup Document(E:) partition Completely to One-drive in such way that whenever I create, update or delete a file or perform any action in Document Partition, it is also updated in my One-drive.

Comment: I used to use a software package called Tera copy that allowed synchronizing of folders, I believe also on a schedule. Hope that helps

Comment: @Comos but i think it is used to copy files not to backup them.

Comment: 1. I think you can configure `OneDrive` Windows application to sync the root folder of "E:" drive. 2. I'd advise asking it in `superuser.com` community.